# How to fix a border with gaps in a given rect?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to draw a dotted border and a 'rectangular' border around an image but i'm struggling in how to calculate the space/position of the dots to their borders be correctly aligned.

Current using my code the borders mismatch in the intersections:

```
void drawDottedCircle(cv::Mat& image, cv::Rect rectangle, int dotSize, int gapSize, cv::Scalar dotColor)
{
    // Draw dots along the top and bottom edges
    for (int x = rectangle.x; x <= rectangle.x + rectangle.width; x += dotSize + gapSize) {
        cv::circle(image, cv::Point(x, rectangle.y), dotSize / 2, dotColor, -1);
        cv::circle(image, cv::Point(x, rectangle.y + rectangle.height), dotSize / 2, dotColor, -1);
    }

    // Draw dots along the left and right edges
    for (int y = rectangle.y + dotSize + gapSize; y < rectangle.y + rectangle.height; y += dotSize + gapSize) {
        cv::circle(image, cv::Point(rectangle.x, y), dotSize / 2, dotColor, -1);
        cv::circle(image, cv::Point(rectangle.x + rectangle.width, y), dotSize / 2, dotColor, -1);
    }
}


void drawDottedRectangle(cv::Mat& image, cv::Rect rectangle, int rectSize, int gapSize, cv::Scalar rectColor)
{
    // Draw rectangles along the top and bottom edges
    for (int x = rectangle.x; x <= rectangle.x + rectangle.width - rectSize; x += rectSize + gapSize) {
        cv::Rect topRect(x, rectangle.y, rectSize, rectSize);
        cv::Rect bottomRect(x, rectangle.y + rectangle.height - rectSize, rectSize, rectSize);
        cv::rectangle(image, topRect, rectColor, -1);
        cv::rectangle(image, bottomRect, rectColor, -1);
    }

    // Draw rectangles along the left and right edges
    for (int y = rectangle.y + rectSize + gapSize; y < rectangle.y + rectangle.height - rectSize; y += rectSize + gapSize) {
        cv::Rect leftRect(rectangle.x, y, rectSize, rectSize);
        cv::Rect rightRect(rectangle.x + rectangle.width - rectSize, y, rectSize, rectSize);
        cv::rectangle(image, leftRect, rectColor, -1);
        cv::rectangle(image, rightRect, rectColor, -1);
    }
}

int main() {

    cv::Mat img(300, 300, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0));
    
    drawDottedCircle(img, cv::Rect(10, 10, 280, 280), 10, 5, cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255));
    drawDottedRectangle(img, cv::Rect(50, 50, 170, 90), 5, 5, cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0));
    int y = 0;

}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: you'll either need to accept your current result or make sure your boxes are a multiple of the size of your dots/boxes

Comment: Or you can equally distribute the maximal number of dots or rectangles that fit in the expected range ...

Comment: @Markus how, and how it will be aligned?

Answer (score 0):

You can distribute the maximal number of dots that fit into the expected range. This will adjust the gap according to width and height, respectivly. I hope you are fine with pseudo code:

```
drawDottedCircle(image, rect_x, rect_y, width, height, dotSize, gapSize, dotColor) {
    count_x = int(width / (dotSize + gapSize))    // maximal number that fits in width
    count_y = int(height / (dotSize + gapSize))   // maximal number that fits in height

    for i = 0, 1, ..., count_x {
        x = rx + int(float(width) * i / count_x)  // linearly distribute to i-th position
        circle(image, (x, rect_y), int(dotSize / 2), dotColor, -1)
        circle(image, (x, rect_y + height), int(dotSize / 2), dotColor, -1)
    }

    for i = 0, 1, ..., count_y {
        y = ry + int(float(height) * i / count_y) // linearly distribute to i-th position
        circle(image, (rect_x, y), int(dotSize / 2), dotColor, -1)
        circle(image, (rect_x + width, y), int(dotSize / 2), dotColor, -1)
    }
}
```